# Huge Data Processing in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt, gwt-platform

I am having a bunch of records (approx 10k) and need to be encrypted at the client side and then traverse over the network with RPC call . The Encryption process and traversing to server takes long time for 10k records. Is there any way so that the time can be reduced.

Time for Encryption takes : 1:10 Minutes
Time for sending and receiving back the 10k records from Client to Server and Server to Client  takes : 3:46 Minutes

Server is on GoDaddy - US and am accessing from India.
Client machine Configuration : Currently 4GB Memory (which may be less in real time , might be 1GB or 2GB)
Server Machine Configuration: 4GB

Encryption is done at client side only.

The Java Objects are being traversed in List and Map Collections.

Comment: Without more information nobody can answer this.  What is "a long time"? How fast is the network? How much of the time is encryption vs network transmission?  Please edit the question and show some evidence that you've made an attempt to gather basic information.

Comment: Encrypt it faster. Get a faster network.

Comment: What is a "record", is it a `String`, a java `Object` or a `File`? How big is reach record in `bytes` or `kilobytes`? Hard to suggest improvements without more details.

Comment: Encryption in javascript and sending data over an RPC call. Why would anyone in their right do this? What's wrong with just sending the data over HTTPS?

Comment: @Strelok : The encryption is being done using the Client's Certificate. So it need to be done at Client's Machine only.

Answer (score 1):

Try running without debug and see how long it takes.

Answer (score 1):

Well here are some thoughts:

**Speeding up client-side encryption**:

Are you using a 3rd party library to do encryption? I don't think you will be able to improve this much with Javascript. You could look for another library which might be faster.

However you might also look into [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/).
This allows you to run C/C++ code in the Chrome sandbox with nearly native speed. However right now it only works in the latest Chrome versions.

You could have the JS encryption library as a fallback for all other browsers (Firefox, Safari, IE)

**Speeding up sending to backend/server**

I can only think of using some kind of client side compression library to compress the encrypted 10k records before sending it to the server.

Comment: Encryption is done by JS and Applet using the Certificates of the Client. For now we are testing on FireFox only.